# SQLException is never thrown only global Exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, error-handling, sqlexception

I am trying to provoke error in MySql to get SQLException in spring but without succes. SQLException is never thrown only global Exception. **I am tring to delete record typing a name witch is not aloud to delete and in MySql it is a error: "Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row.."** This is in MySql and it should be like this. When I try it true controller **I got 500 error response, just Exception and it should be SQLException.**

I am putting code from delete method:

```
@Override
public void deleteCity(String name)throws SQLException {
    if(cityRepo.findByName(name)==null)throw new NullPointerException("No city with entered name");
    City city = cityRepo.findByName(name);
    cityRepo.delete(city);
}
```

Here is controller:

```
@DeleteMapping(path = "/city/delete")
public void deleteCity(@Valid @NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be empty")
                       @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name) throws SQLException {
    cityService.deleteCity(name);
}
```

Global handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(SQLException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleArgumentException(SQLException sqlExc, WebRequest request) {
    log.error("SQL database exception occured - check database", sqlExc);

    return buildErrorResponse(sqlExc, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, request);
}
```

I tried with my class like to extend SQLException but it is same behavior. Anyone knows the problem?

Comment: Spring doesn't throw checked exceptions like `SQLException`, it only throws unchecked exceptions. I don't know which one, but if you temporarily add an `@ExceptionHandler` for `Exception.class` you can catch it, inspect it, and then use that instead of `SQLException`.

Answer (score 0):

Should you try to put this at your CityService

```
@ExceptionHandler(SQLException.class)
public void handleSQLException() {}
```

It's will tell Spring Boot how to handle SQLException

 hope it's work